# How can I get the total number of pages in DOMPDF?

Tags: php, dompdf

For example `Page 1 of 5`.

There's an [example online](http://pxd.me/dompdf/www/examples.php#print_header_footer.html,html) of how to get teh `Page 1` part but not the `of 5` part. This is it:

```
.pagenum:before { content: "Page " counter(page); }
```

I'm using version 0.6 and `$PAGE_NUM` and `$PAGE_COUNT` does not work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default, inline PHP is disabled for security reasons, you need to enable it yourself in dompdf_config.custom.inc.php. See [here](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/wiki/Usage#Inline_PHP_support).

For now, total page count is not supported with the CSS you are using, we are planning to make it work in 0.6 final though.

Comment: If you want to right-align the page num/count, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/13378393/6632

Comment: Is it now possible to get the total number of pages in dompdf? Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

**For people coming here using a new version of DomPdf**

> Since [`dompdf`](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/releases) **`0.7.0`**, the `dompdf_config.inc.php` file has been removed (and is no longer referenced): all dompdf options should be set at run time.

This means you have to create a new instance of `Options` class

```
$domPdfOptions = new Options();
```

And then you may enable PHP inline using the following line

```
$domPdfOptions->set("isPhpEnabled", true);
```

The rest of the codes are correct and will show a page number and page count

```
<script type="text/php">
    if (isset($pdf))
    {
        $x = 72;
        $y = 18;
        $text = "{PAGE_NUM} of {PAGE_COUNT}";
        $font = $fontMetrics->get_font("helvetica", "bold");
        $size = 6;
        $color = array(255,0,0);
        $word_space = 0.0;  //  default
        $char_space = 0.0;  //  default
        $angle = 0.0;   //  default
        $pdf->page_text($x, $y, $text, $font, $size, $color, $word_space, $char_space, $angle);
    }
</script>
```

**Update**
As pointed out by @london-smith, this also works for DomPDF 0.8.1

Answer (score 5):

Check you have enabled inline_pdf in dompdf.

Use this code, you can put where you like, it gets the height and width of the document and puts the page/total_pages at the bottom right.

```
<script type = "text/php">
if ( isset($pdf) ) { 
    $pdf->page_script('
        if ($PAGE_COUNT > 1) {
            $font = Font_Metrics::get_font("Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif", "normal");
            $size = 12;
            $pageText = $PAGE_NUM . "/" . $PAGE_COUNT;
            $y = $pdf->get_height() - 24;
            $x = $pdf->get_width() - 15 - Font_Metrics::get_text_width($pageText, $font, $size);
            $pdf->text($x, $y, $pageText, $font, $size);
        } 
    ');
}
```

[Seen at the end of this page](https://code.google.com/p/dompdf/wiki/Usage#Inline_PHP_support)

Comment: This worked for me! Thanks.
Seems like using `$pdf->page_script('')` is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

See the attachment named issue121.php on this bug report.  Worked for me.  As I understand it you can't echo the page num but you can draw it somewhere.

http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/issues/detail?id=121

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is mi full code... after all the HTML put this..

```
<?
require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html(ob_get_clean());
$dompdf->render();
$canvas = $dompdf->get_canvas(); 
$font = Font_Metrics::get_font("helvetica", "bold"); 
$canvas->page_text(512, 10, "Página: {PAGE_NUM} de {PAGE_COUNT}",$font, 8, array(0,0,0)); 

$filename = "yourNameConvention".date("Y-m-d").'.pdf';
$dompdf->stream($filename);
?>
```

Test with a simple file, then put all the relevant code with querys, etc.. etc..

Answer (score 0):

I dont know which kind of content you want to render.
I got a bunch of pictures and a maximal Pictures per Site constant.

So a function gives me the site number (total/max) and then I got everything I need to start creating the pdf.

```
@for ($i = 1;$i <= $pages; $i++)
@if ($i !== 1) 
   <div style="page-break-before: always;"></div>
@endif
   #Code for each Site
@end
```

Thats how I seperate my Sites and their I also got $pages as a blade variable.

```
<div class="info_footer">
     Page <span class="pagenum"></span> / {{$pages}}
</div>
```

With Stylesheet:

```
.pagenum:before { content: counter(page); }
```

Answer (score -1):

`$PAGE_COUNT` is the total number of pages.

#### Example

```
<script type="text/php">
if (isset($pdf) ) {
    echo $PAGE_COUNT;
}
</script>
```

[Documentation](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/wiki/Usage#Inline_PHP_support)

#### Update

If you are using an old version where this is not supported, upgrade. Otherwise, you may be out of luck.

Answer (score -1):

In php, you can access dompdf variables:

```
$PAGE_NUM       the current page number
$PAGE_COUNT     the total number of pages in the document
```

more info http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/wiki/Usage

Comment: Then you've found a bug. I would consider testing if the bug in 0.6beta2 still exists, or check  - if it is a regression - that 0.6b1 fixes this. Dompdf is quite unstable unfortunately.