# dompdf page number

Tags: php, dompdf

Hi I am using DOMPDF to generate PDF file, I would like to know how to get page number.

I have try the following as mention in FAQ page of DOMPDF. and not successful.
NOTE: I also have turn on inline PHP as well as it mention in FAQ

following is my code

```
 <?php
require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");


ob_start();
//be sure this file exists, and works outside of web context etc.)


$dompdf = new DOMPDF();


$html="     <script type='text/php'>";
        if ( isset($pdf) ) { 
            $font = Font_Metrics::get_font("yourfont", "normal");
            $size = 9;
            $y = $pdf->get_height() - 24;
            $x = $pdf->get_width() - 15 - Font_Metrics::get_text_width("1/1", $font, $size);
            $pdf->page_text($x, $y, "{PAGE_NUM}/{PAGE_COUNT}", $font, $size);
        } 
$html.="        </script>";

$html .="
        aaaaa<br/>aaaaaa<br/>aaaaaa<br/>aaaaa<br/>aaaaaa<br/>aaaaaa<br/>aaaa<br/>aaaaa<br/>aaaaaa<br/>aaaaa<br/>
        aaaaa<br/>aaaaaaa<br/>aaaaaa<br/>
aaaaa<br/>aaaaaa<br/>
        aaaaaaa<br/>aaaaaaaaaa<br/>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br/>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br/>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br/>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br/>
        aaaaaaa<br/>aaaaaaaaaa<br/>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br/>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br/>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br/>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br/>
        aaaaaaaa<br/>aaaaaaaaa<br/>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br/>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br/>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br/>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br/>
        aaaaaaaa<br/>aaaaaaaaa<br/>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br/>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br/>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br/>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br/>
        aaaaaaaa<br/>aaaaaaaaa<br/>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br/>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br/>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br/>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br/>
        aaaaaaaaa<br/>aaaaaaaa<br/>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br/>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br/>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br/>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br/>
        aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br/>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br/>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br/>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br/>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br/>
        </body></html>"; 


$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("sample.pdf");


 ?>
```

Can someone point me out this issue please? where did i make it wrong

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are running your inline script as part of the PHP page instead of passing it to dompdf. Your code *could* be written as follows (truncated to the relevant section):

```
...
$html="
<html>
  <body>
    <script type='text/php'>
      if ( isset($pdf) ) { 
        $font = Font_Metrics::get_font('helvetica', 'normal');
        $size = 9;
        $y = $pdf->get_height() - 24;
        $x = $pdf->get_width() - 15 - Font_Metrics::get_text_width('1/1', $font, $size);
        $pdf->page_text($x, $y, '{PAGE_NUM}/{PAGE_COUNT}', $font, $size);
      } 
    </script>
";
...
```

*Note that inline script must currently appear inside the BODY element. Otherwise it will be ignored during document processing.*

[There are other ways to achieve what you want as well](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7484318/264628).

Answer (score 0):

Where you have '1/1' being used to get $x, this won't work when you have more than 10 pages.

A possible solution does mean editing "cpdf_adapter.cls.php", so the _add_page_text() function used the following just after the str_replace()... about line 790:

```
if ($x < 0) $x = (($this->_width + $x) - $this->get_text_width($text, $font, $size));
if ($y < 0) $y = (($this->_height + $y) - $this->get_font_height($font, $size));
```

The idea is that you can pass in negative x/y coords, and they will work from the right/bottom edges.

Then in the HTML thats sent to DOMPDF, I used:

```
<script type="text/php">
   $pdf->page_text(-30, -32, "{PAGE_NUM} of {PAGE_COUNT}", Font_Metrics::get_font("serif"), 10, array(0,0,0));
</script>
```

Or if you want to specify the x/y in px:

```
<script type="text/php">
   $pdf->page_text(((-30 * 72) / DOMPDF_DPI), ((-32 * 72) / DOMPDF_DPI), "{PAGE_NUM} of {PAGE_COUNT}", Font_Metrics::get_font("serif"), 10, array(0,0,0));
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Code that worked for me. You can customize where is should be located depending on the size of your PDF:

```
$pdf->load_html($html);
$pdf->render();
$dompdf = $pdf->getDomPDF();
$color = array(0, 0, 0);
$font = null;
$size = 10;

$canvas = $dompdf->get_canvas();
$canvas->page_text(0, 0, "{PAGE_NUM} of {PAGE_COUNT}", $font, $size, $color);
```

Remember that color array doesn't contain RGB values. Appropriate values you can take from row RYB [here](https://encycolorpedia.com/777777) as a value in range (0,1), i.e. `array(0.46,0.46,0.46)`.