# Laravel 5 domPDF PAGE_NUM and PAGE_COUNT

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, dompdf

I implemented with success domPDF ([barryvdh-DOMPDF Wrapper for Laravel](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf)) in my Laravel 5 project.

The report is rendering fine, but I was unable to add to my PDF report parameters (like in CodeIgniter): PAGE_NUM, PAGE_COUNT, date and other stuff in the header or footer of the report.

Do you have any solutions to this issue?

My code in Laravel 5:

```
$data['company'] = Company::find($company_id)->name;
$dompdf = PDF::loadView('admin.inputs.report',$data)->setPaper('A4');
```

In CodeIgniter was simple to insert a header:

```
$canvas = $this->dompdf->get_canvas();
$font = Font_Metrics::get_font("helvetica", "bold");
$canvas->page_text(36, 18, "Page: {PAGE_NUM} from {PAGE_COUNT}", $font, 6, array(0,0,0));
return $dompdf->stream('invoice.pdf');
```

Comment: It would help to see your usage.

Comment: @BrianS I updated the question with code...

Comment: Maybe something like `$canvas = $dompdf->getDomPDF()->get_canvas();` to get the canvas object? Then I think you should be able to just add your `page_text` line from CodeIgniter and render the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Enable PHP in your dompdf (version: 0.6.*, [domPDF](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf))

Change DOMPDF_ENABLE_PHP to true in dompdf.php config (file path: "...\vendor\barryvdh\laravel-dompdf\config").

> 2. Add lines to your pdf view:

```
<script type="text/php">
 $text = 'page: {PAGE_NUM} / {PAGE_COUNT}';
 $font = Font_Metrics::get_font("helvetica", "bold");
 $pdf->page_text(36, 18, $text, $font, 9);
</script>
```

Comment: Font_Metrics not found :(

Comment: Note that for version >= 0.7, you should be using [Dennis Ameling's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38788676/5727643).