# How to insert page number using barryvdh/laravel-dompdf

Tags: laravel-5, package

I have been trying to insert page number using the package barryvdh/laravel-dompdf. But so far I am unsuccessful. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Look here
https://code.google.com/p/dompdf/wiki/FAQ

Also here is question on github
https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/issues/37

Found my answer by looking over the `dompdf_config.inc.php` file. As it turns out, `DOMPDF_ENABLE_PHP` is set to false thus causing the inline php script to be ignored. I simply edited `dompdf_config.custom.inc.php` to the following and all is fine and working with the later code in the view.

**In dompdf/dompdf_config.custom.inc.php**

```
<?php
    define("DOMPDF_ENABLE_PHP", true);
```

**Then, in my html file**

```
<body>
    <script type="text/php">
        if ( isset($pdf) ) {
            $font = Font_Metrics::get_font("helvetica", "bold");
            $pdf->page_text(72, 18, "{PAGE_NUM} of {PAGE_COUNT}", $font, 6, array(255,0,0));
        }
    </script>
    <div
```

If you go this route, don't forget to restart Apache

source [How to get page number on dompdf PDF when using "view"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19983610/how-to-get-page-number-on-dompdf-pdf-when-using-view)

Comment: Note that for version >= 0.7, you should be using [Dennis Ameling's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38788676/5727643).

Comment: is there any way that we can use a dynamic variable in each page instead of PAGE_NUM? Ex: different usernames on each page