# page number in laravel dom pdf

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, dompdf

I'm using laravel framework in php.

I have Generated the plugin by using this `barryvdh/laravel-dompdf`

And now my question is how to create the page number for seprate page in pdf like page 1 and page 2 like this  in `barryvdh/laravel-dompdf` ?

```
<?php
require_once("dompdf_config.inc.php");

$html =
  '<html><body>'.
  '<p>Put your html here, or generate it with your favourite '.
  'templating system.</p>'.
  '</body></html>';

$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("sample.pdf");

?>
```

Comment: What code do you currently have, and what have you tried?

Comment: above code is working fine but i cant get the page number of pdf

Comment: The `barryvdh/laravel-dompdf` package is just a wrapper for dompdf, have you read the original dompdf documentation?

Comment: https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki

Comment: able to use page number in document @Jeemusu

Answer (score 0):

For the page count you can use CSS counters.

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  .page-num:before { content: counter(page); }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Page <span class="page-num"></span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately dompdf does not yet support the total number of pages using counters (for text similar to "page 1 of 3"). For that you would have to use script.

```
<?php
require_once("dompdf_config.inc.php");

$html = '...';

$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();

$pdf = $dompdf->get_canvas()->get_cpdf();
$x = 10; // from left
$y = 10; // from bottom
$text = "Page {PAGE_NUM} of {PAGE_NUM}"; // {PAGE_NUM} and {PAGE_COUNT} are placeholders populated by dompdf
$font = Font_Metrics::get_font("arial", "normal");
$size = "10"; // in pt
$color = array(.3, .3, .3); // rgb, valid values are between 0 and 1
$pdf->page_text($x, $y, $text, $font, $size);

$dompdf->stream("sample.pdf");
?>
```

*Note: the above script snippet is specific to v0.6.x using the CPDF backend.*

Comment: Note that for version >= 0.7, you should be using [Dennis Ameling's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38788676/5727643).