# How to add page number in laravel dompdf?

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, laravel-5.3, dompdf

I add `$pdf->set_option('isPhpEnabled', true);` is like this :

```
public function listdata()
{
    $data = User::all();

    $pdf=PDF::loadView('print_tests.test_pdf', ['data' => $data]);
    $pdf->set_option('isPhpEnabled', true);
    $pdf->setPaper('L', 'landscape');
    return $pdf->stream('test_pdf.pdf');
}
```

In body (View) I add like this :

```
<script type="text/php">
    if ( isset($pdf) ) {
        // OLD 
        // $font = Font_Metrics::get_font("helvetica", "bold");
        // $pdf->page_text(72, 18, "{PAGE_NUM} of {PAGE_COUNT}", $font, 6, array(255,0,0));
        // v.0.7.0 and greater
        $x = 72;
        $y = 18;
        $text = "{PAGE_NUM} of {PAGE_COUNT}";
        $font = $fontMetrics->get_font("helvetica", "bold");
        $size = 6;
        $color = array(255,0,0);
        $word_space = 0.0;  //  default
        $char_space = 0.0;  //  default
        $angle = 0.0;   //  default
        $pdf->page_text($x, $y, $text, $font, $size, $color, $word_space, $char_space, $angle);
    }
</script>
```

There is exist error like this :

```
FatalThrowableError in PrintTestController.php line 21: Call to undefined method Barryvdh\DomPDF\PDF::set_option()
```

Note :

I using barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.7.0" (v0.7)

Is there any people who can help to me?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, I'm still confused. This : `$dompdf->set_option("isPhpEnabled", true);`. It was placed in controller or where?

Comment: That is correct. at run time (currently how you have it in the controller) is fine.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, But why still error. It looks like my code is correct

Comment: [`setOptions()`](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/blob/master/src/PDF.php#L133), i suppose? instead of `set_options()`

Comment: @Bagus Tesa, It's the same. It's not working

Comment: any changes on the error?

Comment: @Bagus Tesa, `Call to undefined method Barryvdh\DomPDF\PDF::setOptions()`

Comment: well, getting desperate enough.. have you take a look inside that file? `Barryvdh\DomPDF\PDF` it should be around your `vendor/barryvdh/dompdf/src/PDF.php` - just to be sure, check which one exist, the `setOptions` or `set_options` or something else..

Comment: @Bagus Tesa, Nothing

Comment: Note that for version >= 0.7, you should be using [Dennis Ameling's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38788676/5727643).

Answer (score 0):

Please use `setOptions()` instead of `set_option()`

```
public function listdata()
{
  $data = User::all();

  $pdf = PDF::loadView('print_tests.test_pdf', ['data' => $data]);
  $pdf->setOptions(['isPhpEnabled' => true]);
  $pdf->setPaper('L', 'landscape');
  return $pdf->stream('test_pdf.pdf');
}
```

and for page number,

1. First of all please don't use something like `<script type="text/php">`...
2. There is no function as such as page_text and nor is $pdf passed to the view, instead the data is.

The only way page number can be added is using `page-breaks`

```
<style>
.page-break {
    page-break-after: always;
}
</style>
```

Add that to your view and then by yourself add page numbers as text.

Comment: There is exist error like this : `Call to undefined method Barryvdh\DomPDF\PDF::setOptions()`

Comment: @samueltoh It seems there is no `setOptions()` in 0.7.0.... Please do `composer remove barryvdh/laravel-dompdf` and then `composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf`

Comment: It's failed. Look here : http://postimg.org/image/8glbaktz1/

Comment: @samueltoh Remove The Service Provider from app.php

Comment: I do this : http://postimg.org/image/kpasalzwf/. It's the same. There exist error like this : `Call to undefined method Barryvdh\DomPDF\PDF::setOptions()`

Comment: remove service provider : `Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider::class`  from app.php
then run ``composer dump-autoload --optimize``