# How to add page number for every page in laravel dompdf?

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, laravel-5.3, dompdf

I get from here : https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf

My controller is like this :

```
public function listdata()
{
    $pdf=PDF::loadView('print_tests.test_pdf');
    $pdf->setPaper('L', 'landscape');
    return $pdf->stream('test_pdf.pdf');
}
```

My view is like this :

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>header1</th>
        <th>header2</th>
        <th>header3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>content-row-1</td>
        <td>content-row-1</td>
        <td>content-row-1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>content-row-2</td>
        <td>content-row-2</td>
        <td>content-row-2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want every page there is a page number

Is there any people who can help me?

Comment: Have you seen this? The accepted answer can be found here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19983610/how-to-get-page-number-on-dompdf-pdf-when-using-view

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Follow below steps to achieve it:
- Enable `DOMPDF_ENABLE_PHP` from `/config/dompdf.php`
- Publish vendor file via `php artisan vendor:publish command`
- Pass `$pdf` object from controller:
- Add below code inside the view file:

```
<script type="text/php">
    if ( isset($pdf) ) {
        $font = Font_Metrics::get_font("helvetica", "bold");
        $pdf->page_text(72, 18, "Header: {PAGE_NUM} of {PAGE_COUNT}", $font, 6, array(0,0,0));
    }
</script>
```

You can get more idea from [Page count and page number](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/issues/37)

Comment: Note that for version >= 0.7, you should be using [Dennis Ameling's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38788676/5727643).

Comment: here are a  solution https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/issues/452

Answer (score 10):

Try this one.

```
<style>
   .pagenum:before {
        content: counter(page);
    }
</style>
<body>

    <span class="pagenum"></span>

    <table>
        <tr>
          <th>header1</th>
          <th>header2</th>
          <th>header3</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td>content-row-1</td>
          <td>content-row-1</td>
         <td>content-row-1</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>content-row-2</td>
        <td>content-row-2</td>
        <td>content-row-2</td>
     </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 8):

you can do like that for example..

in your controller :

```
$pdf = app('dompdf.wrapper');
$pdf->getDomPDF()->set_option("enable_php", true);
$data = ['title' => 'Testing Page Number In Body'];
$pdf->loadView('welcomeView', $data);
```

in your `welcomeView.blade.php`

```
<html>
 <body>
   <h1> {{ $title }} </h1>

   <script type="text/php">
    if (isset($pdf)) {
        $x = 250;
        $y = 10;
        $text = "Page {PAGE_NUM} of {PAGE_COUNT}";
        $font = null;
        $size = 14;
        $color = array(255,0,0);
        $word_space = 0.0;  //  default
        $char_space = 0.0;  //  default
        $angle = 0.0;   //  default
        $pdf->page_text($x, $y, $text, $font, $size, $color, $word_space, $char_space, $angle);
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: May I know what is font?

Answer (score 0):

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('print_tests.test_pdf');

$pdf->render();

$dompdf = $pdf->getDomPDF();
$font = $dompdf->getFontMetrics()->get_font("helvetica", "bold");
$dompdf->get_canvas()->page_text(34, 18, "{PAGE_NUM} / {PAGE_COUNT}", $font, 10, array(0, 0, 0));

return $pdf->stream('test_pdf.pdf');
```

The `page_text()` acts on each generated page, and it is expected that pages have already been generated within the document when it is called. The starting `$pdf->render()` call is intended to trigger that action, in particular when large tables (spreading across multiple pages) are included in the document.