# dompdf - How to add page number using view with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, dompdf

I integrate `dompdf` inside my laravel projet.
I return a blade view as PDF and works all fine but I don't know how to show number of pages.

For example I want to show in header Page 1 of 4 ... Page 2 of 4 ... etc

This is how I return the PDF:

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('file-pdf', $data);
  return $pdf->download('filename.pdf');
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add page number for every page in laravel dompdf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41272819/how-to-add-page-number-for-every-page-in-laravel-dompdf)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to your vie.
Make sure you have `"DOMPDF_ENABLE_PHP" => true,` in dompdf.php. also, make sure your content doesn't pass php code unescaped since that would leave arbitrary code to be run as said in dompdf docs.

```
<script type="text/php">
if (isset($pdf)) {
   $font = $fontMetrics->getFont("Arial", "bold");
   $pdf->page_text(555, 745, "Page {PAGE_NUM}/{PAGE_COUNT}", $font, 7, array(0, 0, 0));
}
</script>
```