# How can I customize page number in laravel dompdf?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, dompdf

I get from here : https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf

My controller is like this :

```
public function listdata()
{
    $pdf=PDF::loadView('print_tests.test_pdf');
    $pdf->setPaper('L', 'landscape');
    return $pdf->stream('test_pdf.pdf');
}
```

My view is like this :

```
<script type="text/php">

    if ( isset($pdf) ) {
        $x = 72;
        $y = 18;
        $text = "{PAGE_NUM} of {PAGE_COUNT}";
        $font = $fontMetrics->get_font("Arial", "bold");
        $size = 6;
        $color = array(0,0,0);
        $word_space = 0.0;  //  default
        $char_space = 0.0;  //  default
        $angle = 0.0;   //  default
        $pdf->page_text($x, $y, $text, $font, $size, $color, $word_space, $char_space, $angle);
    }

</script>
```

I use this :

> "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.8.0",

When executed, the page number not display.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Have you loaded the "Arial" font into Dompdf? If not then you should try using "Helvetica" instead, or the more generic "sans-serif".

Comment: @BrianS. No. Because I want to use Arial. I had change it to Helvetica. But the page number not display

Comment: Is there no one to help? I've made some questions, but no answers help

Comment: Are you saying the page number doesn't display when you using Helvetica?

Comment: @BrianS, No. When I use arial, it also does not work

Comment: It _should_ work when using Helvetica as that's a core PDF font. Also important, make sure your embedded script is contained inside the `<body>` element otherwise Dompdf will ignore it.

Comment: Note that for version >= 0.7, you should be using [Dennis Ameling's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38788676/5727643).

Answer (score 1):

You've used `<script>` tag with PHP type,

its just an other way to tell the parser that the code between the tags is in PHP.

However it is not recommended to use, because some browsers may not translate it correctly. Use the normal PHP code.

```
<?php ?>
```

Comment: @Pandhi Bhaumik, It's the same. I follow here : https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/issues/37

Comment: @samueltoh, then there might be some error in console. have you checked it? is your PHP error reporting is enabled?

Comment: FYI, the `script` tag it a means of running some Dompdf PHP code during processing.

Comment: Not sure about that, this seems feature of dompdf then.