# Is there way to pass script php to jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I found script type text/php when I using dompdf library, I want to try pass value inside text/php to text/javascript.
so I have code like this with `type="text/php"`

```
<script type="text/php">
        $myText = 'This is My text';
</script>
```

and  i want to pass value to jquery

```
<script type=text/javascript>
$('.tess').text($myText);
</script>
```

and my html like this `<div class="tess"></div>`, this should return `"This is my text"`
it's possible to pass it?

for reference see this question, dompdf uses script type=text/php and I want to pass it into jquery so I can get the value [How can I get the total number of pages in DOMPDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486376/how-can-i-get-the-total-number-of-pages-in-dompdf)

Comment: `PHP` is a server-side language which is executed before any client-side languages such as `javascript/jQuery` but you can `echo` things into the DOM script or you could use `ajax` to call your `php` file...

Comment: If that was possible everyone in the world could read your code. Also PHP code is executed at the server and not at the client. You need to install XAMPP for windows or if you are working on ubuntu, install it via apt install php.

Comment: @arundeepchohan return error, sure undifined variable

Comment: @NewToJS I don't really understand ajax, that's why I only discuss jquery. maybe you can include an example with ajax?

Comment: The only way to understand the use of `AJAX` is from researching it and testing it out for yourself. If I create an example it would mean including comments of each step and usage which will then turn into a tutorial. Sorry.

Comment: <div class="tess">
<?php include 'something.php'

echo " $myText.";

?> 


</div>   something like this perhaps? https://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_include3